# TCP server doubling inputs

Tags: python, server, tcp

I am currently developing a simple TCP server using gevent. This is the current code:

```
from gevent.server import StreamServer

SIZE = 1024
DISCONNECT_INPUT = "\q"

def clientSocket(socket, address):
    print(f"[{address}] Connection established.")
    socket.send(f"Welcome to the server. Type {DISCONNECT_INPUT} to exit.".encode())

    dataList = []

    while True:
        message = socket.recv(SIZE).decode()

        if message:
            if message == DISCONNECT_INPUT:
                print(f"[{address}] Client closed connection.")
                break

            else:
                print(f"[{address}]: {message}")

                dataList.append(message)
                socket.send(message.encode())

        else:
            print(f"[{address}] Client disconnected.")
            break



server = StreamServer(("127.0.0.1", 5000), clientSocket)
print("Listnening for connections...")
server.serve_forever()
```

Connections are handled just fine, but inputs are received per character instead of per line. For example, if I connect via telnet and try to type "this is a message", the server receives and reads every character I type instead of waiting for the full thing. To better illustrate what I mean:

Here's what the server looks like after typing "this is a message" on telnet:

[image]

And this is what the telnet window looks like:

[image]

(The server is an echo server hence why the telnet looks like it does.)

I don't know exactly what would be causing this. Is this a telnet issue or a code issue?

Comment: Can you add your client code as well?

Comment: There is no client code, I am connecting via telnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with a tool like Wireshark what is really sent.
I think telnet sends as soon as possible, to allow using an application that needs single key strokes, like editors or nethack.

TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol, so there is no guarantee, that message boundaries are preserved. If you want to echo line by line, you have to collect until you receive the \n.

Comment: I think you might be right, I tested it on an ubuntu VM using netcat and it works as intended, so this most likely a telnet issue.